# Router store does not recognize router params

Tags: angular, angular6, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-router-store

We have the following routing scenario:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':userId',
    component: fromContainers.OrganizationComponent,
    canActivate: [],
    children: [
      { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'posts' },
      {
        path: 'posts',
        loadChildren: './views/posts/posts.module#PostsModule'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Our router store does not recognize `userId` this way but when we remove the `children` property it does recognize the value of `userId`.

```
http://localhost:4200/user/r1RORssFG --> WORKS
http://localhost:4200/user/r1RORssFG/posts --> DOES NOT WORK
```

What is the reason behind this behavior?

Comment: Are you getting an error on the console at all?

Comment: No errors at all and we can validate that the `userId` is not read when we check the Redux DevTool

Comment: what do you mean by `does not recognize`? the serialited paramsMap value does not contain `userId`?

Comment: `http://localhost:4200/user/r1RORssFG` in this route the `userId` param has the correct value
`http://localhost:4200/user/r1RORssFG/posts` in this one `userId` param has no value @Jota.Toledo

Comment: again, when you mean `has no value`, you refer to the serialized state or what? how are you trying to access that value?

Comment: Please try with rearranging the child routes, put at last with path = '' in the child array, that should works.

Comment: It is not working. the `userId` is a param `/user:${userId}` the id param is empty in BOTH angular router and ngrx router in when I do `/posts'

Comment: I mean by no value that the param is not recognized at all both `key` and `value`, it does not exist

Comment: did you configured `paramsInheritance` in the Router.forRoot method?

Answer (score 7):

Based on the hint from [Jota.Toledo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5394220/jota-toledo) ,The solution was to define a routing configuration where I use `Router.forRoot()` like this:

```
export const routingConfiguration: ExtraOptions = {
  paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always'
};
```

and then

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes,routingConfiguration),
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are unable to access params of a parent route from a child route.

To access parent params from child component:

Use `this._route.parent.params` instead of `this._route.params`

where `this._route` is `private _route: ActivatedRoute`

Comment: This a correct but a bad approach though, as its not really refactor friendly. Changes done to the routes definition would break this.

Comment: well, I think differently, its a handy approach, when you know that routings not gonna change.